# Why it didn't print?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, shellcode

simple asm for  ptint the string "/bin/sh" and then exit

```
    global _start:
_start:
    jmp what
are:
    mov rbx,0x68732f6e69622fff
    shr rbx,0x8
    push rbx
    mov rsi,rsp
    mov dl,0x8
    xor rax,rax
    mov al,1
    syscall
    xor rax,rax
    mov al,0x3c
    syscall
what:
    call are
```

`nasm -f elf64 test.asm
ld -o test test.o`

Run as expected .

but use in shellcode :

```
const char shellcode[] = "\x48\xbb\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x48\xc1\xeb\x08\x53\x48\x89\xe6\xb2\x08\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05";

int main(){
    ( (void (*)(void))&shellcode )();
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o test2 test.c`

it prints nothing.

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes `rdi` == 0, 1, or 2, and that 56 high bits of `rdx` are zero. This happens to be true at the start of the process. It just isn't true at the point where you call your shellcode.

To fix, you need to set `rdi` to 1 (if you want the output to be to standard output) or 2 (for output to go to standard error), and set `rdx` 8.

---

The syscall ABI in Linux on x86-64 is

- syscall number in `rax`
- `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and pointer parameters in `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`, and `r9` registers, respectively
- return value will be in `rax`; most syscalls return `-errno` if an error occurs

  (the actual `errno` variable is a C library construct, and the kernel does not know anything about it)
- `rcx` and `r11` are clobbered (may be modified by the syscall); all other registers are preserved

Thus, for `write` (`SYS_write` == `__NR_write` == 1) you set `rax` == 1; `rdi` == descriptor number (`STDOUT_FILENO` == 1 for standard output, `STDERR_FILENO` == 2 for standard error); `rsi` == pointer to the data to be written, and `rdx` == the number of chars to be written.

Comment: @Nominal Animal, why no mention of r10?  x86_64     rdi    rsi    rdx    r10    r8     r9